# How do i add text to a specified column over a sql request (as example add an email to an already registered user)

Tags: mysql

i want to add in my databse the function if a user wants to add his email that it gets added in the right column.

I use azures mysql server and tried Insert into already but then found out UPDATE is the way to go, but i still have some issues

```
UPDATE Accounts SET("e-mail") VALUE (@email) WHERE Username = @Username;
```

My expected result is that it updates the e-mail variable but it doesn't, instead it shows me:

> Wrong Syntax near '('. '.', ID, PSEUDOCOL, QUOTED_ID or VARIABLE is expected.

So what i am asking is, how do i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the syntax for a mysql `UPDATE`, using variables. Here is how you do it :

```
SET @Username := 'Foo';
SET @email := 'foo@bar.com';
UPDATE Accounts 
    SET email = @email
    WHERE Username = @Username;
```

Does your database field is really named `e-mail` ? It is not a good idea to use special characters (here, the dash) in field names. You would need to quote it in every query, like :

```
SET `e-mail` = @email
```